# htaccess: If the requested URL doesn't contain a specific string, redirect user to different domain while maintaining the slug

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have looked through quite a few different posts on here without any luck.

I have two sites (for example):  exampledomain.com and mb.exampledomain.com

If a user accesses mb.exampledomain.com and the URL ***doesn't*** contain the string "retreat", then I want to redirect them to exampledomain.com while maintaining the slug.

So:

mb.exampledomain.com/retreat (or) mb.exampledomain.com/retreat_sunday should be accessible to the user as normal

mb.exampledomain.com/ (or) mb.exampledomain.com/about-us should redirect to exampledomain.com/ (or) exampledomain.com/about-us respectively.

I need to achieve this by using rules in a .htaccess file at the root of the directory.

Additionally, the htaccess rule shouldn't impact the accessibility of asset files on the mb.exampledomain.com/retreat page(s).

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/retreat
RewriteRule ^ https://exampledomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,END]
```

That catches all requests to URLs not *starting* with the literal string "retreat". Which is what you examples demonstrate. If you only want to check for the string itself, regardless of where in the path it occurs, then that should do what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !retreat
RewriteRule ^ https://exampledomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirect and to only change it into a 301 permanent redirect once you are certain everything works as expected.